# Continuity of function with bounded gradient

Tags: analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

Suppose that a real-valued function $f$ is defined on an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ and that all the first-order partial derivatives of $f$ exist at every point in $U$. Also, there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $||\nabla f(x)|| \leq M$ for all $x \in U$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $U$.

This is the variation of Theorem 9.19 in Rudin's PMA. For the proof, I just mimicked the proof of Theorem 9.19 in PMA as follows:

Fix $x_0 \in U$. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset U$. Fix $x \in B(x_0,\epsilon)$ and define $\gamma(t)=(1-t)x_0+tx$ for $ 0 \leq t\leq 1$, then every point of $\gamma$ is in the ball because the ball is convex. Now let $g(t)=f(\gamma(t))$.

Then, I'd like to say that $g'(t)=\nabla f'(\gamma(t)) \bullet \gamma'(t)$, where $\bullet$ means the usual dot product in $\mathbb R^n$.

However, I wonder if I can write this way because the differentiability of $f$ is not guaranteed even if the first-order partial derivatives always exist.

Does anyone have any ideas to modify the solution, or justify my reasoning? Is there any error to this problem?

Comment: It's enough to do it for any open ball.

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite.  However you *can* take a path there which is made up of piecewise lines, each parallel to a partial derivative.  And along each of those paths it *is* differentiable.

And now your argument works perfectly.